# Clique percolation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, clique-problem

I have searched for long time and I couldn't realize what is the best way for finding clique percolation.
As I see it, there are 2 methods

1. Find cliques of size k in graph G and then create a graph between adjacent clique nodes.
2. Find maximal cliques of size >= k-1 and then create a graph between adjacent clique nodes.

Well as I know finding max-cliques is NP-Complete problem, and as I have understood finding k clique in graph G is polynomial, so is the first method is more efficient?
I'd be happy if someone can help and clarify the issue,
Thank you.

Comment: I assume you already read the relevant Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_percolation_method). It says: _Since even small networks can contain a vast number of k-cliques, the implementation of this approach is based on locating the maximal cliques rather than the individual k-cliques. Thus, the complexity of this approach in practice is equivalent to that of the NP-complete maximal clique finding, (in spite that finding k-cliques is polynomial)._ Also note that the use of size (k-1) in the definition differs from your second item.

Comment: k-clique is polynomial for fixed k. In fact best known algorithm is n^k and I don't think n^k algorithm is a good approach in practice. you can use SAT solvers etc to apply heuristic algorithms.